# How to perform like on MongoDB document for integer values

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

At the moment, I currently have a "like" statement that works great for strings.

```cs
Builders<Book>.Filter.Regex("subject", new BsonRegularExpression(searchString.ToString(), "i"));
```

At the moment I'm trying to query the years and possibly search by 2 digit pattern such as `99`, `98`.

Some of the options I currently have in the documents are `2000, 1998, 1997, 1996`.

If I query 98, the document with 1998 should be selected.

Unfortunately, the regex didn't work, wondering if I may get any tips or suggestions for integer number pattern with MongoDB C#.

Comment: If searching with "99", should include the document with "1998", "1997", or query for last 2 digits?

Comment: You can use date range $in [98,99,1998,1999]. Else sort by date and write < > query

Comment: @YongShun should  include 1998 and 1997 if searched for 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work the regex with a numeric value, you need to cast it to a string first.

To do so, you need `$regexMatch` and `$toString` operators. As both operators are aggregation operators, you need to use `$expr` as well.

I think there is no supported feature/function for these operators in MongoDB .Net Driver, but you can provide the query as a `BsonDocument`.

```cs
filterDefinition &= new BsonDocument("$expr",
    new BsonDocument("$regexMatch",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "input", new BsonDocument("$toString", "$year") },
            { "regex", year },
            { "options", "i" }
        }
    )
);
```

So the filter query will be translated as below:

```
find({ "subject" : /(?:)/i, 
"$expr" : { "$regexMatch" : { "input" : { "$toString" : "$year" }, "regex" : "98", "options" : "i" } } })
```

> Sample input data

[image]

> Debugging & Output Result

[image]